# How to highlight current folder in Bash prompt?

Tags: unix, bash, terminal, prompt

I'd like to use the `\w` variable in `.bashrc`, but I want the prompt to highlight the current end-directory. Something like this:

```
/usr/local/<strong>bin</strong>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PS1='${PWD%/*}/\[\e[33;1m\]${PWD##*/}\[\e[0m\] \$:  '
```

use bash'isms to manipulate the $PWD for the last component.  COlorize, and add yet even more meta for bash escapes.

Substitute different numbers for 33 for different colors.

personally i hate the path in the prompt, it moves across the screen.  I prefer in the titlebar.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\e]0;$USER@${HOSTNAME%%.*}: $(pwd -P)\a"'
```

**EDIT** changed Quotes on PS1 to single quotes, since it needs to be evaluated **every** time it's printed, not just once when it's read.  Thanks @Gordon

Comment: You need to put the definition of PS1 in single-quotes, or PWD'll be evaluated just once, when it's set.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `$(dirname \w)/\[$(tput bold)\]$(basename \w)\[$(tput sgr0)\]` in `$PS1`. Don't forget the single quotes.